# Separated link and image in list items

Tags: html

Anyone knows, why does it happen? It looks like images and links in list items  are separated. I can't really understand it, because it looks really strange. I have always seen list items that include both images and links under one border. Thx in advice.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::after,
*::before {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
    background: #070A1B;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 120%;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;

}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

.header__top {
    
    justify-content: space-between;
    
    height: 100px;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.header {}
```

```html
<header class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header__top">
        <button class="header__nav">
          <img class="header__nav-img" src="images/menu-btn.svg" alt="menu botton">
        </button>
        <a href="#" class="logo">
          <img src="images/logo.svg" alt="logo" class="logo__img">
        </a>
        <ul class="list">
          <li class="list_item">
            <a href="#" class="list__link">
              <img src="images/twitter.svg" alt="twitter" class="list__img">
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="list_item">
            <a href="#" class="list__link">
              <img src="images/google.svg" alt="google" class="list__img">
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="list_item">
            <a href="#" class="list__link">
              <img src="images/facebook.svg" alt="facebook" class="list__img">
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

idk why, but here we go...

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code. Instead, create an [mcve].

Comment: Done. I have added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is the default [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) value of `baseline` affecting the `img` elements. Setting this to `middle` will allows them align better with the text.

```js
let imgData = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pjxzdmcgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDI0IDI0IiB3aWR0aD0iMjQiIGhlaWdodD0iMjQiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4xIj48cmVjdCB4PSIwIiB5PSIwIiB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiBmaWxsPSJncmVlbiIgLz48L3N2Zz4=';
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(img => img.src=imgData);
```

```css
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<button><img></button>
<a href="#"><img></a>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><img></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The link will still affect the whole image if that´s your concern.
Anyway, you can solve this by changing the "display" value in css.

Try adding "display:block;" or "display:inline-block;" to the "a" element and this way it will cover the whole image.

Comment: That's better, link covers all il item, but it happens again. Still offset.